# there is a bug in texture image for a-frame ar

Tags: aframe

I made a aframe ar. in  I put a texture png.
when I use a png from some url it work some png not,
and when I try with the same png downloaded on my computer it does no work.

Exemple that don't work:

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.6.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/master/dist/aframe-extras.loaders.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>

<body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>

  <a-scene embedded arjs>

 <a-assets>
    <img id="my-texture" src="rubiscube.png">
  </a-assets>

  <a-entity geometry="primitive: box" material="src: #my-texture"></a-entity>

    <a-marker-camera preset='hiro'></a-marker-camera>
  </a-scene>

</body>

but like this it works:



<a-entity geometry="primitive: box" material="src: url(https://static.wixstatic.com/media/2cd43b_b13c89d3859a48129a434265b3ddd1a1~mv2_d_1826_1920_s_2.png)"></a-entity>
```

but that url of image not

https://i2.wp.com/rgvbingo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/bingo-balls-hi-res.png)">

why? what is the difference betwin this 2 images or url 
and why if it work inline url why not offline?

Answer (score 0):

You have to serve the image through a local server like for instance [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server). Browsers don't have access to the local file system. More details on [A-Frame FAQ](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/introduction/faq.html#why-does-my-asset-e-g-image-video-model-not-load)

Comment: thank you ! I'll try like that but the other mistake about png with online url first is woking well the second do not . Have you an idea for that ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by first / second URL. There’s only one in the original questions. It needs links to reproduce the issue.